# Allocating RAM for Play framework application

Tags: scala, memory-management, memory-leaks, playframework

I wanted to ask a question to the **Play Framework devs (scala)**, how to determine the **RAM required for a certain kind of apps**.

Is there any **tool or utility** that helps me **determine the RAM needed to be allocated** for a certain app.

If not could you provide me with your recommendations for RAM allocations for apps with:

- MySQL DB, Web App, API integration to 2-3 vendors.
- Maybe 200 - 3000 users
- Can have medium uploads features, 5mb files max.
- Concurrent users about, 30 - 200 users at a time.

Using Play Scala `2.3.8` and `2.4.x (with play silhouette)` at the moment, on different apps.

Thanks you, any pointers or information will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io).

In "Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala" there is subchapter about "Performance debugging".